# Object does not match target type reflection error

Tags: c#, reflection

I am getting the error `Object does not match target type`. I understand why I should be getting the error. But I am assigning a `double` to a `double`.
I am not sure why I am getting the error in the code below.

The code I am having issue with:

```
...

var specTran = new SpecTran(gapRecord);
foreach (var result in yields._predictions)
{
    var type = specTran.GetType(); // --> {Name = "SpecTran" FullName = "GAP.Models.Database.SpecTran"}
    var prop = type.GetProperty(result.Key); // --> {Double DexaCWT}

    if (prop == null)
        continue;

    prop.SetValue(
        (double)result.Value, // --> {[DexaCWT, 0]}
        specTran);
}
```

PredictionResult class:

```
PredictionResult {
    ...
    public Dictionary<string, double> _predictions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because your arguments to `SetValue` are backwards, per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=net-6.0).

It should be:

```
prop.SetValue(
    specTran,    
    (double)result.Value); // --> {[DexaCWT, 0]}
```

Comment: I feel rather silly now. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You’re welcome! It’s an easy thing to miss.